# How do I send an IR signal from an Arduino

Tags: ir, signal-processing, timing

I want to send a generic (not Sony, etc.) remote's signal from my Arduino.  I have already used a IR decoder program to capture the timing of the signal:

```
int IRsignal[] = {
// ON, OFF (in 10's of microseconds)
    88, 88,
    174, 88,
    86, 86,
    88, 86,
    88, 88,
    86, 86,
    88, 174,
    86, 88,
    86, 88,
    174, 174,
    86, 88,
    86, 2252,
    88, 88,
    174, 88,
    86, 86,
    88, 88,
    86, 88,
    86, 86,
    86, 176,
    86, 88,
    86, 88,
    174, 174,
    86, 88,
    86, 0};
```

Now I need to send this through the IR LED.  I have never written a program that can modulate a signal at this microsecond level.  How would I do this?

Comment: Use a library, like IRremote. Otherwise, you have to setup one of the pwm-timers to generate a 38kHz frequency, and then turn on and off this pwm based on the values you have captured above.

Answer (score 1):

Use the IRRemote library as mentioned and use the IRecord example.  This will allow you to input a signal and then push a button which will send that signal from the infra-red LED on the arduino.

Answer (score 0):

Please, take a look at Ken Shirrif's  [IRRemote](https://github.com/shirriff/Arduino-IRremote) library, as it is what you need. I used it in some project and worked better than other solutions that I coded.

Comment: I think that this is the one I am using, I am having a hard time finding good documentation for 'generic' IR signals (or RAW signals)